# How can improve my text topic classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, nltk, data-science

I am developing a text topic classifier that can label sentences or small questions.
So far it can label around 30 known subjects.

Works well, but it begins to confuse similar questions with each other.

For example these 3 labels:

**1) Label - backup_proxy_intranet:**
How to set up a backup proxy for intranet app?
... and 140 similar questions containing 'backup proxy for intranet app'...

**2) Label - smartphone_intranet:**
How to use intranet app in my smartphone? and
... and 140 similar questions containing 'intranet app in my smartphone'...

**3) Label - ticket_intranet:** How to relate a ticket order with the intranet app?
... and 140 similar questions containing 'ticket order with the intranet app'...

After training these 3 always returns the label **backup_proxy_intranet**.
what can i do to separate them?

```
series = series.dropna()
series = shuffle(series)

X_stemmed = []
for x_t in series['phrase']:
    stemmed_text = [stemmer.stem(i) for i in word_tokenize(x_t)]
    X_stemmed.append(' '.join(stemmed_text))

x_normalized = []
for x_t in X_stemmed:
    temp_corpus=x_t.split(' ')
    corpus=[token for token in temp_corpus if token not in stops]
    x_normalized.append(' '.join(corpus))

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x_normalized,series['target'],random_state=0,test_size=0.20)

vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3)).fit(X_train)
X_train_vectorized = vect.transform(X_train)

sampler = SMOTE()
model = make_pipeline(sampler, LogisticRegression())
print()
print("-->Model: ")
print(model)
print()
print("-->Training... ")
model.fit(X_train_vectorized,y_train)

filename = '/var/www/html/python/intraope_bot/lib/textTopicClassifier.model'
pickle.dump(model,open(filename, 'wb'))
filename2 = '/var/www/html/python/intraope_bot/lib/textTopicClassifier.vector'
pickle.dump(vect,open(filename2, 'wb'))
```

Best Regards!

Comment: FYI label 2 and 3 are the same. Both are `smartphone_intranet`

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with `ngram_range`? I'm also kind of leaning towards this being off topic for a programming stackexchange. I feel like this belongs in stats or something

Comment: thks Ian, I tried with (1,4), (1,5) and I do not see significant changes.

Comment: please tell me, were you able to tag with multiple topics?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use a TfidfVectorizer from sklearn : it should help you take increase the score !

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     "Label - backup_proxy_intranet: How to set up a backup proxy for intranet app? ... and 140 similar questions containing 'backup proxy for intranet app'"
...     Label - smartphone_intranet: How to use intranet app in my smartphone? and ... and 140 similar questions containing 'intranet app in my smartphone'...
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Comment: Hi Tropiquo! I tried it, It improve the score a bit but it still confuses the labels

Comment: Hi @NicolasBolzan ! What is your confusion matrix / score ?

Answer (score 0):

I got best results using multinomial Naive bayes also from scikit learn